# Examples of some functions with the following conditions

Tags: functions

Find $f$ and $g$, functions of one variable such that $\text{dom}(g\circ f) \supset \text{dom}(f) \cap f^{-1}(\text{dom}( g)).$ Now I tried using rational functions like $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = \frac{x+1}{x+2}$ but somehow I can't get the condition. Any examples? Note that the set containment is strict. I know this is easy, please tell if I am working with right kind of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strict set containment you describe is not possible.

To prove this, let $x \in \operatorname{dom}(g \circ f)$. Then necessarily $x \in \operatorname{dom}(f)$ and $f(x) \in \operatorname{dom}(g)$. The second statement here implies that $x \in f^{-1}(\operatorname{dom}(g))$. Therefore $x \in \operatorname{dom}(f) \cap f^{-1}(\operatorname{dom}(g))$. This lets us conclude that $\operatorname{dom}(g \circ f) \subseteq \operatorname{dom}(f) \cap f^{-1}(\operatorname{dom}(g))$.

Comment: More so, both sets are equal.

Comment: @Jakobian That they are equal would depend on how you define the domain of $g \circ f$, I think. But yes, it is the biggest set on which $g \circ f$ can be defined, so it makes sense to call it the domain.

Comment: Is it possible if the function is multivariable? I see for 1 variable it was simple as you answered.

Comment: I'm guessing you are thinking about examples like $f(x) = 1/x$, with $f\circ f = \text{Id}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}}$, but I wouldn't worry about such things.

Comment: @Rick The argument I gave holds for *any* functions $f$ and $g$ (not even necessarily functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$!), so no, it is not possible.